# WAMP Error: No Host Found. Vhost Setup

Tags: php, mysql, apache, wamp, vhosts

I have been running WAMP locally for about a year, and seemingly for no reason, I am trying to go to my project homepage (using my vhost "cevans.local", which references this folder C:/wamp/www/healthsnap/) and getting this error:

> dial tcp: lookup cevans.local: no such host

I have searched the web for hours today trying to solve this. I haven't touched anything related to my vhosts setup:

hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost 
127.0.0.1       cevans.local
```

httpd.conf

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
```

..............

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/healthsnap/" 
    ServerName cevans.local 
    ServerAlias cevans.local 
    <Directory "C:/wamp/www/healthsnap/"> 
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    <Directory  "C:/wamp/www">
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I believe what is going on is there is something wrong with my vhosts setup, and the vhost is used on the config file of my project to reference the DB credentials. These same credentials are working fine on phpMyAdmin and another MySQL client.

Also, I am not a web developer.

Comment: Could a recent operating system (Windows 7) update somehow be related?

Answer (score 0):

I had an active VPN connection that caused the issue. When I closed the VPN connection it started to work.

Comment: See this thread: http://superuser.com/questions/723974/wamp-server-unavailable-while-vpn-is-connected - might help with running localhost on wamp and a VPN simultaneously